# Qual a maneira correta de executar uma aplicação web no eclipse?

Tags: java, jsf, eclipse

Estou estudando JSF utilizando a IDE eclipse, mas estou encontrando um certo problema ao executar a minha aplicação. Quando executo a aplicação clicando em cima do projeto em si, ele não parece carregar o meu template criado.

Segue exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, quando eu executo clicando diretamente na página que eu quero exibir, o template é carregado corretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

index.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
template="/WEB-INF/templates/Layout.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">Bem-Vindo</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Layout.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>Log Horizon</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h1>Teste de Layout</h1>
    <hr />
    <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Isso acontece em todos os projetos que eu crio. O que eu poderia estar fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe a URL certo. No primeiro caso você acessa a url `http://localhost8080/Projeto` e no segundo momento `http://localhost8080/Projeto/faces/index.xhtml`. A diferença fica clara após isso, no primeiro caso você está acessando a página sem passar pelo framework do `JSF` e no segundo caso ele passa pelo processamento do framework. Caso deseje que a página `index.xhtml` seja automaticamente processada pelo framework configure seu `web.xml` da seguinte forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Não tinha percebido esse detalhe faces. Muito obrigado, Lucas.